# Проблемы с преобразованием данных из byte[] в Double

Tags: java, arduino, double, byte

С Arduino приходит число 13 (с датчика). 
По команде `$ cat /dev/ttyACM0`в терминале все правильно отображается.
А вот в java приложении вместо 13 отображается "1.086239310882075E-71".

**Код фрагмента, отвечающего за преобразование:**

```
public void buffer(){
    buffer = serialPort.readBytes(8);
    System.out.println(toDouble(buffer));
}
public double toDouble(byte[] buffer) {
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer).getDouble();
}
```

Как же мне решить проблему?

Comment: @zRrr, а почему readBytes(2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как быстро я нашел ответ на свой вопрос.
В конец цикла (а у меня цикл) надо прописать

```
serialPort.closePort();
```

Также, требуется сделать строку по типу

```
new String(serialPort.readBytes(2), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)
```

**P.S.** Огромное спасибо zRrr, чей комментарий я включил в этот ответ.

Comment: Вам все-таки стоит выяснить, как именно данные пишутся в порт на стороне ардуино, там, наверное, не каждый раз "13". В jSCC, если я правильно угадал, есть метод `readString()`. Странно, что нет поддержки `InputStream`, как в rxtx, возможно было бы удобно завернуть его в `BufferedReader`, и читать построчно.

Comment: @zRrr, там данные с датчика, они всегда число. С rxtx у меня проблемы были (покопайтесь в моих вопросах, если интересно). Поэтому, сменил на другую либу.